# Python: разделить стандартный ввод и вывод по разным консолям

Tags: python, python-3.x, консоль

Как запустить один процесс Python и получать вывод в одном окне терминала, а ввод производить в другом?

Я про консольные приложения, без Tkinter и т.п.

Операционная система: Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение задачи для **Linux**:

Создаем файл `tst.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

while True:
    s = input('Введите строку: ')
    print(s)
```

Открываем консоль №1, выполняем: `tty`

В результате будет нечто вроде: `/dev/pts/24`

Открываем консоль №2, выполняем: `python ./tst.py > /dev/pts/24`

В результате имеем ввод на консоли №2, а вывод на консоли №1.

Для Windows мне на ум только всякие клиент-серверы приходят, еще можно в файл (возможно в socket) перенаправлять: `python tst.py > out.log`, а оттуда читать.

Comment: Кажется, у меня есть идея, касательно оптимизации импортов в вашей программе...

Comment: Это не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: Автору, судя по всему, этого было достаточно.